# TextField format style url is nil for valid URL

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## Overview

There is a text field that accepts a URL
If the URL is valid then it needs to be assigned to a variable `url`

## Implementation

- Using `TextField("URL", value: $url, format: .url, prompt: Text("URL"))` returns nil for valid URL `https://www.apple.com`

## Problem 1

1. Type in `https://www.apple.com` in URL field
2. Tap on name field
3. Notice URL field has become nil

## Problem 2

1. Type in `https://www.apple.com` in URL field
2. Press button save
3. Notice URL is printed as nil

## My observation based on testing

### Press save

- Doesn't work: `https://www.apple.com` prints `url = nil`
- Works: `https://www.apple.com/a` prints `url = https://www.apple.com/a`

### Tapping on name field

- Doesn't work: `https://www.apple.com` URL field becomes empty
- Doesn't work: `https://www.apple.com/` URL field becomes empty
- Works: `https://www.apple.com/a` URL shows as originally typed

## Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var url: URL?
    @State private var name = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("URL", value: $url, format: .url, prompt: Text("URL"))
                .keyboardType(.URL)
            TextField("Name", text: $name, prompt: Text("Name"))
            Button("save") {
                if let url {
                    print("url = \(url)")
                } else {
                    print("url is nil")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have updated the question with better formatting, see if it is more clear now

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry about that, that was a typo, Under save, 2nd point works, I have updated the question. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Note that `https://www.apple.com/` is working as well so you need that / at the end. I haven't been able to find any relevant documentation for this though. Off topic but I added the modifier `.foregroundColor(url == nil ? .red : .green)` to the TextField for a quicker feedback

Comment: The biggest problem was tapping on the name field even after adding `/` at the end makes it nil. So I ended up doing my custom formatter (not perfect) but works. Text color is a good idea to give visual indication, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the URL format style. [Here's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/formatstyle) the documentation.

In your case you want to omit the path if it is only a single `/`. You can check every part of the URL. Here I've also allowed queries since they are often part of website URLs.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let urlStyle = URL.FormatStyle(path: .omitWhen(.path, matches: ["/"]), query: .omitWhen(.query, matches: [""])) // <- Customise your URL Style Format

    @State private var url: URL?
    @State private var name = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("URL", value: $url, format: urlStyle, prompt: Text("URL")) // <- use your custom format here// <- use your custom format here
                .keyboardType(.URL)
            TextField("Name", text: $name, prompt: Text("Name"))
            Button("save") {
                if let url {
                    print("url = \(url)")
                } else {
                    print("url is nil")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution works perfectly, thanks a lot!! Could you please explain how you arrived at the solution, thanks!!!!